# Grid data not being displayed in ExtJs app

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I'm using ExtJs 4.1.0 and I'm trying to display a grid of data backed by a remote json store. When I render the grid like so:

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({enabled:true});
Ext.Loader.setPath({
    'Grip':'app'
    ,'Ext.ux':'ext/examples/ux'
});
Ext.require([
    'Grip.view.EditableGrid'
    ,'Grip.store.UYNMeetingTypes'
    ,'Grip.view.UYNMeetingGrid'
    ,'Grip.model.UYNMeeting'
    ,'Grip.store.UYNMeetings'
    ,'Ext.ux.CheckColumn'
]);

Ext.require([
    'Ext.panel.*',
    'Ext.toolbar.*',
    'Ext.button.*',
    'Ext.container.ButtonGroup',
    'Ext.layout.container.Table',
    'Ext.tip.QuickTipManager'
]);

Ext.onReady(function() {

    var store = new Grip.store.UYNMeetings();
    grid = new Grip.view.UYNMeetingGrid({
        store: store
        ,renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
    store.load({
        // store loading is asynchronous, use a load listener or callback to handle results
        callback: function(){
            Ext.Msg.show({
                title: 'Store Load Callback',
                msg: 'store was loaded, data available for processing',
                modal: false,
                icon: Ext.Msg.INFO,
                buttons: Ext.Msg.OK
            });
        }
    });
});
```

it works fine. However, when I try to link things up using the manner suggested in the MVC tutorial (http://www.sencha.com/learn/architecting-your-app-in-ext-js-4-part-2/) I can't seem to get my data to display. I'm running ExtJs 4.1.0 on Google Chrome 20.0.1132.47. Any ideas?

I tried to post only the minimally relevant bits of code (though it still seems like a lot). Let me know if there's anything I can clarify. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Grip.controller.UYNMeeting:

Ext.define('Grip.controller.UYNMeeting', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

```
refs: [{
    ref: 'meetingGrid',
    selector: 'uynmeetinggrid'
}],

stores: ['UYNMeetings','UYNMeetingTypes'],

init: function() {

},

onLaunch: function() {
    var meetingsStore = this.getUYNMeetingsStore();        
    meetingsStore.load({
        callback: this.onMeetingsLoad,
        scope: this
    });
    var meetingTypesStore = this.getUYNMeetingTypesStore();        
    meetingTypesStore.load({
        callback: this.onMeetingTypesLoad,
        scope: this
    });
},

onMeetingsLoad: function() {
},

onMeetingTypesLoad: function() {
    Ext.Msg.show({
        title: 'Store Load Callback',
        msg: 'store was loaded, data available for processing',
        modal: false,
        icon: Ext.Msg.INFO,
        buttons: Ext.Msg.OK
    });
}
```

});

Grip.view.UYNMeetingGrid:

```
var rowEditing = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {
    clicksToMoveEditor: 1,
    autoCancel: false
});

Ext.define('Grip.view.UYNComboBox', {
    extend:'Ext.form.field.ComboBox'
    ,alias:'widget.uyncombo'
    ,stores:['UYNMeetingTypes']
})

Ext.define('Grip.view.UYNMeetingGrid', {
    extend:'Ext.grid.Panel'
    ,alias:'widget.uynmeetinggrid'

    ,stores:['UYNMeetings']
    ,title:'UYN Meetings Grid'
    ,hideHeaders: true

    ,bodyPadding:5
    ,width:550
    ,height:400
    ,autoScroll: true

    ,initComponent:function(){
        this.columns = [{
            "width": 150,
            "text": "Name",
            "sortable": true,
            //"id": "name",
            "dataIndex": "name",
            editor: {
                allowBlank: false,
                xtype: 'textfield'
            }
        },
        {
            "width": 150,
            "text": "Org.",
            "sortable": true,
            //"id": "org",
            "dataIndex": "org",
            editor: {
                allowBlank: true,
                xtype: 'textfield'
            }
        },
        {
            "width": 100,
            "text": "Date",
            "sortable": true,
            //"id": "date",
            "dataIndex": "date",

            editor: {
                xtype: 'datefield',
                allowBlank: false,
                format: 'm/d/Y',
                maxText: 'Cannot have a meeting date in the future!',
                maxValue: Ext.Date.format(new Date(), 'm/d/Y')
            }
        },
        {
            "width": 75,
            "text": "Meeting Type",
            "sortable": true,
            //"id": "meeting_type",
            "dataIndex": "meeting_type"/*,
            editor: {
                xtype: 'uyncombo'
            }*/
        },
        {
            "width": 75,
            "text": "Num Hours",
            "sortable": true,
            //"id": "num_hours",
            "dataIndex": "num_hours",
            editor: {
                allowBlank: false,
//                 step: '.1',
                xtype: 'numberfield'
            }
        }];

        this.dockedItems = [{
            dock:'bottom'
            ,xtype:'toolbar'
            ,items: [{
                xtype:'button'
                ,text:'New'
                ,action:'newuynmeeting'
            }, {
                xtype:'button'
                ,text:'Edit'
                ,action:'edituynmeeting'
            }, {
                xtype:'button'
                ,text:'Remove'
                ,action:'removeuynmeeting'
            }]
        }];

        this.callParent();
    }

    ,plugins: [rowEditing]
    ,listeners: {
        'selectionchange': function(view, records) {
//          grid.down('#removeEmployee').setDisabled(!records.length);
        }
    }


});
```

Grip.view.Viewport:

```
Ext.define('Grip.view.Viewport', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',
    layout: 'fit',

    requires: [
        'Grip.view.ContactsPanel'
        ,'Grip.view.UYNMeetingForm'
        ,'Grip.view.UYNMeetingGrid'
        ,'Grip.view.NavBar'
    ],
    renderTo: 'app',
    tbar:{
        xtype:'mynavbar'
    },
    items:[{
        xtype:'tabpanel',
        items:[{ 
            title:'Contacts',
            xtype:'tabpanel',
            items:[{
                title:'Contacts'
                ,xtype:'contactspanel'
            },{
                title:'Add Contact'
                ,html:'TODO: Add content'
            }
            ]
        },{
            title:'UYN',
            xtype:'tabpanel',
            items:[{
                title:'UYN Meetings'
                //,html:'Foo'
                ,xtype:'uynmeetinggrid'
            }]
        }]
    }]

});
```

Comment: I don't know if it's a typo, but a grid doesn't have a `stores` config - it can only display the data of one store, thus it has `store` config (singular, not plural)

Comment: Well I feel silly... Thanks! Not sure when I introduced that bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it's a typo, but a grid doesn't have a `stores` config - it can only display the data of one store, thus it has a `store` config (singular, not plural)